# null pointer exception in Android app after changing language setting

Tags: android

My Android app crashes with a null pointer exception after I open it, go to Settings and change languages from English(United States) to English(United Kingdom), and then return to the app. Changing language from English to Spanish also causes a crash.

The app crashes due to a `ViewPager` object becoming null. This object is created in the `onCreate()` method of the activity and is accessed in other location in my code but never changed or recreated.

I haven't done anything to localize my app so that it works for languages other than English(United States).

```
public class TabMainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    ActionBar actionBar;
    ActionBar.Tab popsVideoTab, corralStatusTab, reportsTab,currentStatusTab, storeStatusTab, supportTab;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabmain);
    actionBar = getActionBar();     
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Creating ActionBar tabs.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
    {
         @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {
        }
    });
}


public int pagerGetCurrentItem()
{
    int pagerCurrentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    return pagerCurrentItem;
}
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>
```

The Stack Trace is as follows.

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=4.4.2
APP_VERSION_NAME=4.5.2
BRAND=samsung
PHONE_MODEL=SM-T210R
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carttronics.storeport/com.carttronics.storeport.TabMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4041)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1311)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.carttronics.storeport.TabMainActivity.pagerGetCurrentItem(TabMainActivity.java:507)
at com.carttronics.storeport.CurrentStatusFragmentTab.onCreate(CurrentStatusFragmentTab.java:95)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1879)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:215)
at com.carttronics.storeport.TabMainActivity.onCreate(TabMainActivity.java:66)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5459)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1):

After you change language the Activities OnDestroy method is called and then the onCreate method is called. The onCreate activity created a new ViewPager for my app. My app has several fragments, one of which had onResume() called and accessed the ViewPager object before it was recreated again.

I put null checks around all references to the ViewPager and the app no longer crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's garbage collected, but you should check if viewPager != null.
If you want to store an index, you may save it throuh the bundle 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html
in : onSavedInstance

Comment: I added an onDestroy() to my activity and it does get called when I switch languages and then bring the app forward again.